# React change css variables from react component for css keyframes

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to create a component called `CarouselItem` which is functioning as an object within a carousel display, I want these items to have different opacities depending on how close to the middle of the carousel they are and fade to fully opaque when hovered over, to do this i need the CSS to be able to access a variable of the component state to see how opaque they should be before they are hovered. I read this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752138/in-react-how-to-pass-a-dynamic-variable-to-a-const-css-style-list) on stackoverflow which talks about using an arrow function to create a style and use that in the react style but because i want to include keyframes I'm not sure how i would implement this. Any ideas on how to implment or other solutions that may work?

**CSS used in fade in animation**

```
.fade {
  animation: fade-in-keyframes 2s;
}
@keyframes fade-in-keyframes {
  from {opacity: 0}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

(the from portion of the fade in keyframes section should use the variable from the react component instead of 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily use styled-components. You can pass your component state as a prop to your CSS. it's very easy to use and I actually have code that I think could help you a lot
I will share the link with you

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/water-drop-navbar-g6wmxv)

if you go to my styled.js file you will see my code
You can write a function that will generate keyframes based on your props. I think it will help a lot on this matter

```
const WaterDrop = styled.div`
animation-duration: 0.3s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-timing-function: linear;
// this is the part that you you send the data as props to use it on your css
animation-name: ${({ keyFrameStep }) => goDownKeyFrame(keyFrameStep.start, 
keyFrameStep.end)};
`;
```

this is how you pass you data

```
<WaterDrop keyFrameStep={keyFrameStep} />
```

and this the function I used to generate  different keyframes based on my needs

```js
const goDownKeyFrame = (start, end) => {
  if (start > end) {
    return keyframes`
    0% {
      top: ${
        circleHeightWidth *
          (totalAmountOfCircle % 2 === 0 && totalAmountOfCircle === start
            ? start - 1
            : start) +
        circleVerticalMargin * (2 * start - 1)
      }px;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: ${borderRadius}px;
  }
  50%{
      background-color: white;
  }
  100% {
      top: ${
        circleHeightWidth * end + circleVerticalMargin * (2 * end + 1)
      }px;
      border-radius: ${borderRadius}px;
      background-color: rgb(255,116,0);
  }
    `
  } else if (start < end) {
  return keyframes`
  0% {
    top: ${
      circleHeightWidth * (start + 1) +
      circleVerticalMargin * (2 * start + 1)
    }px;
    border-radius: ${borderRadius}px;
}
50%{
    border-radius: 0px ${borderRadius}px ${borderRadius}px;
}
100% {
    top: ${
      circleHeightWidth * end + circleVerticalMargin * (2 * end + 1)
    }px;
    border-radius: ${borderRadius}px;
}
  `
  }
}
```

the js file won't work if you want see how it is work I strongly suggest to check out my codesandbox link

if you use Replit or StackBlitz

[Replit](https://replit.com/@farbodesham/water-drop-navbar)

[Stack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/water-drop-navbar?file=src/index.js&hideDevTools=1)